# How can I do snmp v3 queries using DH on Debian 11?

Tags: snmp

snmp tool: net-snmp v5.9
os:  Debian 11

I saw an article [here](https://wagtail-prod-storage.s3.amazonaws.com/documents/1743_Schauer_3272_paper.pdf) that gives an example using DH (I assume this means diffie-hellman).

```
snmpget \
-v 3 \
-l authPriv \
-u v3localKeys \
-3k 0xf9c96a9232ee65a08aa9085e6f1ff82c \
-3K 0xedebac85112645218fb7a63659a332c2 \
10.168.6.21 \
system.sysUpTime.0
```

My version of snmpget doesn't say anything in --help or man about -3k or -3K options. How can I do snmp v3 queries using DH on Debian 11?

Comment: Are you having problems using the `-3[kKmM]` options, or just curious why you don't see them in `snmpget --help` ?  `man snmpcmd` for documentation on the command line options common to all the net-snmp command line tools.

Comment: I'm having trouble with the -3 options.  I do see reference to -3 in that man page you mentioned.  Thanks.